# Solve WiFi / Bluetooth frequency conflict

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, wifi-configuration

When I connect my Bluetooth sound speaker my WiFi slows down. Sometimes it doesn't open anything anymore. I read it's a conflict due to radio frequency but I couldn't find any settings to change it on Windows.

Comment: Some combo devices are known to work poorly as you describe. There's no solution other than getting better hardware.

Comment: Better hardware? can't I change the frequency it's transmited? I've read peple said that have done so, I just didn't find how so far

Comment: No, you can't change the frequency. If the WiFi supports both 2.4GHz and 5GHz then, obviously, using only the latter may have a positive effect.

Comment: You *can* change the WiFi frequency easily by selecting specific channels. WiFi and Bluetooth both use 2.4 GHz band.

Answer (score 1):

If your WiFi is using the 2.4 MHz band, i.e. variants 802.11b, 802.11g or 802.11n, it is *possible* that [Bluetooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth), which uses frequencies of about 2400 to 2484 MHz and [WiFi](http://www.radio-electronics.com/info/wireless/wi-fi/80211-channels-number-frequencies-bandwidth.php) in the 2400 - 2500 MHz region, are interfering with each other. You can check this by changing the channels your router users: consult the manual for the specific router, e.g. [Netgear](https://kb.netgear.com/23783/Improving-2-4Ghz-Wireless-Performance-by-Changing-Channel), [XFinity](https://www.xfinity.com/support/articles/change-wifi-admin-tool-xfinity-xfi) etc. There is information on the web for changing the channel, e.g. [How-To Geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/197268/how-to-find-the-best-wi-fi-channel-for-your-router-on-any-operating-system/). Since this is an easy, free, adjustment, it won't hurt to try it.

Another possibility is that *Power Options, Advanced settings* for the wireless adapters is reducing throughput. Be sure it is set to **Maximum Performance**, though this might slightly reduce operating time on battery.

[image: Wireless Adapter Power Options]

However, it is also possible, as @MichaelBay states, that your PC can't handle the throughput from two wireless devices. You *could* try an [external WiFi](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01CCMUN8C) or [Bluetooth USB device](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0775YF36R) to take some load off your PC, or to use the 5 GHz WiFi band, if your router can do so, but if the CPU itself is the limiting factor, these will not help.

Comment: Did you mean 2.400 to 2.484 MHz instead of 2400 to 2484 MHz?

Comment: @FedericoGentile, No, that's 1,000 lower in the RF spectrum it would be in the low shortwave or high broadcast frequencies at 2.4 MHz